# How to navigate between fragments with tab view on click in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Can anybody help regarding navigation between fragments using tabview onclick method.

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: @sasikumar i am using tab view, but requirement is to open and navigate fragment on each tab onclick method. My tabview is with custom style.